# Laptop with unlocked/K Intel CPU and a SSD

Tags: laptop, processor, intel

I need a new laptop with at least a 128Gib SSD (without spinning drive) and Nvidia graphic gard and 16GB of RAM and **unlocked Intel CPU**. Not for overclocking or getting better CPU performance but for [changing execution speed of games](http://web.archive.org/web/20191129151711/https://superuser.com/questions/1506110/how-to-multiply-sleep-timings-for-a-specific-program-on-windows-or-linux) and [various programs which requires to complete tasks in a limited time the same way](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/138380).
This also requires a laptop BIOS/EFI setup which allows changing such timings.

[This mean a CPU model with a K in the name like i7-6700K or i9-9900HK for example](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-numbers.html).

In terms of CPU Power, I don’t want many cores. I want the fastest per thread performance.

I saw many high‑end new and used laptop for sale. But none of them featured a [CPU which allowing to have its clock speed capped below normal speed](https://superuser.com/q/1506110).

Comment: The whole point of doing the contrary of overclocking is to change the Time Stamp counter increase speed.

Comment: Don’t know if [that one](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Eurocom-Sky-X4C-Core-i9-9900KS-Laptop-Review-Unlocked-Desktop-Processor-in-a-Mobile-Form-Factor.444756.0.html) has a ʙɪᴏꜱ allowing to tune the settings.